# How can I optimize a search for elements of an array within another array

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an initial list of elements in common

```
val commonList = mutableListOf<String>
```

I have the following object

```
ClassObject(val title: String, val subjects: List<String>)
```

Assuming you have such a list with initial data

```
val list = listOf<ClassObject> /* With a size of 1000 samples */
```

How can I iterate the initial list "list" and look in the list of "subjects" for the elements that are not in "commonList" and add them to this last list.

I had thought of a nested for loop, but it would require a lot of power and time.

```
list.forEach { c -> 
    c.subjects.forEach { s ->
        if (s !in commonList)
            commonList.add(s)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use MutableSet instead of MutableList for this purpose. Using an `in` check on a Set does not require iteration so it is far more performant. It would also make your code a lot simpler, because it won't redundantly add items, so you can simply use an `addAll` call on it to achieve the same thing as if you had first checked if each item is in the set first.

```
val commonSet = mutableSetOf<String>()
val list = listOf<ClassObject>( /*...*/ )
for (classObject in list) { 
    commonSet.addAll(classObject.subjects)
}
```

In Big-O notation, the above is *O(n)*, whereas your original code is *O(n^2)*.

Comment: Thank you, you served me very well. I was doing the experimentation, and the time was reduced up to 2068%. The time is in nanoseconds, barely reaching 0.13 seconds with nested for loops, but with mutable sets I went to 0.006 seconds.

Comment: I did this with a ForEach, but I was reading that depending on the data type, it may be the most suitable for cycle or foreach, it would be enough to test the for cycle and see if it is reduced even more.

Comment: `for` and `foreach` in this case compile to the exact same bytecode, so there is no performance difference between them. Official Kotlin coding conventions state that `for` should be preferred when you aren't iterating at the end of a chain of functional collection operations, but this is really a just a style choice.

Answer (score 1):

So to paraphrase, it seems you want to *accumulate all unique entries* from your nested `list` into a flat list `commonList`.

In which case, using a [`MutableSet`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-set/) would be a good idea. I'm not familiar with the Kotlin implementation of sets, but traditionally they are like hashmaps that don't map keys to values but instead hold unique keys. The difference from a simple `List` being that they are internally more sophisticated than a plain array, and benefit from faster collision look-ups.

In conclusion, you can't really avoid the nested loop, but you can eliminate the wasteful `!in` check. If you must end up with a list at the end, you can always call `toList` on the set.